# Can't login using my login username and password

Tags: login

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 along side Windows 8. During the installation, I saved my username and password as required. When I boot, I see login screen. Login and Guest. when I login with my username and password, I keep getting invalid username and password.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

To recover password you need to follow these steps:

1. Boot your computer.
2. When you get the grub menu, select option with recover mode.
3. This will take you to recovery menu. In recovery menu select option "drop to root shell"
4. A shell prompt will be displayed at the bottom of the screen with root as username. To change the password of particular user say username type:

   passwd username
5. The above command will ask you to enter your new password and retype password. Type your new password.
6. You might get "Authentication Manipulation error". If you get this error then you need to type :

   mount -rw -o remount /

And again follow step 4 and 5.